# How to return the number of blank cells in a column between entries

Tags: google-sheets

How may I return either an array address of blank cells in a column between entries, or count the number of blank cells until a column holds an entry in Google Sheets?

Answer (score 1):

Counting from the top, the first occupied row number (therefore by deducting `1`, the number of blank cells) before an occupied cell may be determined, for ColumnA with:

```
=ArrayFormula(MATCH(FALSE,ISBLANK(A:A),0))-1
```

Within a more detailed explanation there is an explanation of how the above works, in Excel, at [Exceljet](https://exceljet.net/formula/get-first-non-blank-value-in-a-list). The principle is the same for Google Sheets.

Comment: Thanks so much! Works as expected.